# I cannot change the temporary Directory

Tags: 7

I cannot change the temporary directory under file settings.  Everytime I change it, it says the changes have been made, but it reverts back to the setting it previously had.

I even went as far as deleting the 'dbo.variable.file_temporary_path' value in the database, but it is still not working.

Do you have an idea about where this is being stored?

Answer (score 3):

It was hard coded in the settings.php file. This will override any settings you do in the UI.